# Getting the current process in Windows

Tags: process, kernel

While reading Practical Reverse Engineering by Bruce Dang, I came across the following.

[image: Image from Practical Reverse Engineering]

1. Am I correct in my assumption that the procedures return a pointer to the current thread and current process respectively?
2. In *PsCurrentProcess*, the offset into the current thread is *0B8h* whereas in the comment it is written as *0x70*. I do not understand what the author means by this. In an attempt to find out I tried to debug a x64 Windows 10 Kernel.

   [image]

   [image]

I couldn't find any thing at offsets 70h nor B8h. But I did find a *_KPROCESS* at offset *220h*. Is this what I am looking for?

[image]

3. Will this offset be the same for all Windows 10 x64 systems?
4. I would like to know about the internals of all these structures. Is there any resource that explains all the important internal data structures in Windows from a reverse engineering stand point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, the offsets are more likely to match the current OS at the time of the book's writing (probably Win7) than Windows 10. That said, a good reference to internal kernel structures over different Windows versions is Geoff Chapell's website: https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/index.htm

For example, looking at [`KPCR`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kpcr.htm), we can see that at `0x0180` we have `KPRCB Prcb;`, so 188h is 8 bytes into `KPRCB`. Checking [`KPRCB`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kprcb/amd64.htm?tx=111), in turn, we see that offset 8 is `KTHREAD *CurrentThread;`. So the offset `0B8h` should be looked up in the `KTHREAD` struct. I was able to find on [this page](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kthread/current.htm?tx=109) the member `KAPC_STATE ApcState;` at offset **0x70** in x86 version and **0x98** in x64. 
I'm not sure what OS version is the quoted disassembly coming from, but it looks like there's been some mixup. You should probably submit an errata report on the [book's page at Wiley](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118787315,subjectCd-CSJ0.html).

In the meantime look at the disassembly of mentioned functions in the kernel you're actually running and *then* match it against the structs you're printing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As adviced, I looked into the dissasembly of the function on my system. The offset to ApcState is 0x98 in x64. It seems to be an array. At an offset x20 into the array is the ApcState.Process. So the effective offset is 98h + 20h = B8. Also after googling a lot I found [the terminus project](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/). It shows a nice representation of some internal structures in Windows. Thought you might be interested.

Answer (score 1):

most of these structures can be queried with windbg

if you are running in usermode ntdll.pdb has these type information

if you are running in kernelmode ntos/ntkr/ aka nt*.pdb  has these type information

you can use a tool like livekd from sysinternals along with windbg to do a 
local kernel debugging session

following are output from livekd on a win7 x86 machine as far as possible 
the commands are kept os / version agnostic

the current process can be queried as **? @$proc**

```
kd> ? @$proc
Evaluate expression: -2050188616 = 85cc9ab8
kd>
```

the **single question mark ?** represents masm expresssion evaluator 
you can use **?? question marks** to turn on c++ expression evaluator

```
kd> ?? @$proc->UniqueProcessId
void * 0x00000538
kd>
```

the above Current process pid is also represented by @$tpid

```
kd> ? @$tpid
Evaluate expression: 1336 = 00000538
kd> ?? @$tpid
unsigned int 0x538
kd>
```

the pcr is represented by **@$pcr**

you can mix and match the expression evaluator the @@() lets you insert a c++ expression into a masm evaluation

```
kd> ? @$pcr
Evaluate expression: -2097779712 = 82f66c00
kd> ?  @@(@$pcr->PrcbData.CurrentThread)
Evaluate expression: -2048806120 = 85e1b318
kd>
```

in my system  PsGetCurrentProcess is as follows

```
kd> uf nt!PsGetCurrentThread
nt!PsGetCurrentThread:
82e72b99 64a124010000    mov     eax,dword ptr fs:[00000124h]
82e72b9f c3              ret
kd>
```

you can directly get the raw contents of this segment:offset

```
kd> ? poi(fs:00000124)
Evaluate expression: -2048806120 = 85e1b318
kd>
```

the current thread is denoted by **@$thread**

```
kd> ? @$thread
Evaluate expression: -2048806120 = 85e1b318
kd>
```

ApcState is not an array it is a structure

```
kd> ?? @$thread->Tcb.ApcState
struct _KAPC_STATE
   +0x000 ApcListHead      : [2] _LIST_ENTRY [ 0x85e1b358 - 0x85e1b358 ]
   +0x010 Process          : 0x85cc9ab8 _KPROCESS
   +0x014 KernelApcInProgress : 0 ''
   +0x015 KernelApcPending : 0 ''
   +0x016 UserApcPending   : 0 ''
kd>
```

you can get the offset to Process mention in you post like this

```
kd> ?? &(@$thread->Tcb.ApcState.Process)
struct _KPROCESS ** 0x85e1b368
kd> ?? *(unsigned long *)&(@$thread->Tcb.ApcState.Process)
unsigned long 0x85cc9ab8
kd>
```

in my system PsGetCurrentProcss is as follows

```
kd> uf nt!PsGetCurrentProcess
nt!PsGetCurrentProcess:
82ec5fce 64a124010000    mov     eax,dword ptr fs:[00000124h]
82ec5fd4 8b4050          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+50h]
82ec5fd7 c3              ret
kd>
```

raw query

```
kd> ? poi(30:124)
Evaluate expression: -2048806120 = 85e1b318
kd> ? poi(poi(30:124)+50)
Evaluate expression: -2050188616 = 85cc9ab8
kd>
```

expression query

```
kd> ? @@(@$prcb->CurrentThread->ApcState.Process)
Evaluate expression: -2050188616 = 85cc9ab8
kd>
```